# Facebook API won't logout

Tags: php, facebook

index.php:

```
blablabl
<?php include("fb-api/****-api.php"); ?>
blablabal
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

****-api.php:

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '******',
  'secret' => '***********',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }

?>
```

link:http://music.x-game.info/
Ok, I login without any problems, but when I press the logout link it doesnt logout  me, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using facebook->getlogouturl
redirect the user to another file: logout.php
and include this:

```
  <?php
  $facebook->destroySession();
  session_destroy();
  ?>
```

Comment: This is *NOT ALLOWED* by Facebook because it does not sign the user out from Facebook. According to Policies I.6, `"Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs the user out of Facebook."` taken from https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 1):

After logout, user comes your main page and logins automatically because of $user variable will be set.

You can use a database to control logins/logouts.

Comment: Aham, can I make my index only to check if user is logged in, and if isn't NOT to do it?

Comment: Actually, there is no login/logout function of Facebook. If someone enters the page that runs $user = $facebook->getUser(); code, the $user variable will be always set. You have to use a database that it could be txt file.

Check out database if $user['facebookid'] logged out, then redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the redirect_uri when creating the logout URL to something like `http://yourdomain.tld/logout.php`.

In that script, first initialize the Facebook SDK again, call it’s `destroySession` method, and afterwards call PHP’s own `session_destroy`.

And then redirect to your start page or whatever.